command-line: filter history based on the current command line with CTRL-P
Say that in my command-line history I have the following:
:cd ~/Document
:e myfile.txt
:cd /opt/bin

Then, if I type :cd and then I hit <up> the command become :cd /opt/bin and if I hit <up> again the command become :cd ~/Document, i.e. the history is filtered based on the beginning of the command :cd, as per docs:
<Up>        recall older command-line from history, whose beginning
            matches the current command-line (see below).  See 'wildmenu'

However, if I use CTRL-P, then the history is scanned line-by-line, e.g. if the current command line is :cd and then I hit CTRL-P twice, then the command line is filled with :e myfile.txt, whereas I would like to have :cd ~/Document.
Is there a way to make CTRL-P to behave like <up> for this use case?

Probably :cnoremap <c-p> <up>, but this is documented: :help c_CTRL-P vs. :help c_<Up>

Usch! Sometimes you have the solution under your nose and you can’t see it :D thanks!

Probably :cnoremap <c-p> <up> will do it. The behavior you describe is documented: :help c_CTRL-P vs. :help c_<Up>; consider carefully if you really need the change (or at least consider keeping C-p's behaviour around with :cnoremap <up> <c-p>).
I personally recommend against this in case you use other Vims, as it builds a habit that won't work in Vims without your configuration.
